# What to do with Cycle Notation?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the group $S_6$, you are given $u=(1\,3\,6)$ and $v=(1\,2\,4)(3\,5\,6)$.
Calculate $u^v = vuv^{−1}$ with the fastest possible technique. Explain your work/reasoning. Using your work or otherwise, calculate the commutator $[u, v]$.

I am not entirely sure on how to start this. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I’m seeing some unrecognized characters; are those simply $u=(136)$ and $v=(124)(356)$?

Comment: Yeah, like u = (1,3,6) and v = (1,2,4)(3,5,6)

Comment: Are you able to calculate $u^v$ using any means? It turns out that conjugation of a permutation by a permutation is essentially a kind of "change of basis". I'm hesitant to write a concrete result, as it depends on your convention of function composition (I've been spoiled by using the regular convention, and Isaacs' "$fg$ means *do $f$, then $g$*.")

Answer (score 0):

When you conjugate $(124)(356)$ by $(136)$, you simply apply the transformations of $(136)$ to $(124)(356)$. Thus change 1 to 2, 3 to 6, and 6 to 1.